# Get width of string element without appending

Tags: jquery, dom

**Element:**

```
var dv = "<div style='width:300px;height:100px'></div>";
```

How to I get 300px printed in the output?

```
alert($.parseHTML(dv).width()) //outputs undefined.
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3yq1bgvk/1/

Comment: `$.parseHTML(dv)` will return `array`

Comment: `alert($.parseHTML(dv)[0].style.width);`

Answer (score 1):

You should create DOM element, instead of using `$.parseHTML`

*Use*

```
var dv = "<div style='width:300px;height:100px'></div>";
alert($(dv).width());   //300
```

[image: jsFiddle]